# How long ago was the Universe small enough for interstellar travel?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, universe, estimation, big-bang

Currently, even the nearest stars are lightyears away, and impossible to reach in our lifetimes. If space is always expanding, and was once infinitely smaller, then at what point in the past was space so much smaller that the average distance between stars was less than light days? Was there ever such a time?

Comment: Hi Ben Warner: Welcome to Phys.SE. Did you try to do a back-of-an-envelope-calculation?

Comment: see this https://astronomy.com/magazine/ask-astro/2006/01/how-close-can-stars-get-to-each-other-in-galaxy-cores . We just happen to be around a star at large distance from other stars. " A typical stellar separation at this density works out to 0.008 light-year, or 500 AU — about 12 times the Sun-Pluto distance — between stars."

Comment: Sure, it's impossible for humans to travel that far with current technology, but it's not impossible, in principle. However, no matter what technology is used, it takes a *lot* of energy to travel even 4.5 lightyears in a human lifetime.

Comment: There's already a good answer, but the fundamental confusion that motivated the question may have to do with ambiguous astrophysical references to "particles" as sometimes including objects like stars, or even galaxies, which (like just about everything regarding size) depends (in at least a few Indo-European languages, including English) on the context:  In the context of "spatial" expansion, the main factor accounting for it may be energy, whose particles are bosons, which can pass thru each other.  Whether gravity has any bosonic aspect remains unclear, due to its extreme weakness.

Comment: I don't think that just because things were a few light days apart, meant that they could be travelled between in a few days. Space would have expanded while you were travelling between them, so depending on how fast the expansion was, it may have been that it took a photon years to travel between two points that were, when the photon left the first point, only light days away.

Comment: Some models of the universe have the galaxies, e.g. the Milky Way, forming from combining many smaller clusters/galaxies over time.. so there wouldn't be, like, a denser version of the Milky Way earlier in the universe, but rather many of the stars would probably be further apart.

Comment: Depends on the elements you need for the spaceship. The first stars were 100M~250M years after the BB, and the only elements were hydrogen and helium. You need Population I stars, and those are only 1M~100M years old. So if it's 13.8 *billion* years old, more or less the same size it is now.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As the universe expands each individual galaxy stays roughly the same size, with stars on orbits of roughly constant diameter, so the stars within any given galaxy were no closer together a long time ago than they are now (at least as far as cosmic expansion effects are concerned).

The distances between galaxy clusters were smaller in the past, and a good way to get a sense of this is to note that the ratio of distance between them now to distance between them a long time ago is equal to the ratio of wavelengths in the light received and emitted. If we receive light from a galaxy and the light arriving has a wavelength twice as large as when it set out, then the universe was half as small when the light set out (that is, distances between galaxy clusters were then on average half what they now are).

To find a time when galaxies were not many lightyears apart you have to go so far back that you arrive at times before the formation of galaxies, so there never was such a time.

[*Added remark in answer to a question in the comments concerning galaxy clusters*. One galaxy cluster drifts away from another because the initial conditions gave them velocities of this form. This general condition is called the "Hubble flow" and it leads to the cosmic expansion. It is what things would do if they only experienced the average cosmic gravitation, without any local bumps owing to a non-homogeneous matter distribution such as a galaxy. Meanwhile everything attracts stuff near to it and this can lead to bound groups such as solar systems, galaxies and galaxy clusters. This binding is sufficient to turn the relative velocities around so that each bound group does not drift apart, nor does it expand (unless some other process intervenes).]

Comment: Where stars ever closer together before the formation of galaxies though?

Comment: How does "… each individual galaxy stays roughly the same size but the distances between galaxy clusters were smaller in the past…" work, please?

Here, is there a significant difference between individual galaxies and galaxy clusters?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin It's my understanding that galaxies stick together because the matter in them is gravitationally bound to itself. Eventually, basically all the matter in the reachable universe will be contained entirely in the Milky Way-Andromeda galaxy (long after they've fused together).

Comment: @nick012000 Thanks and together because of gravity doesn't seem to address a difference between galaxies and clusters. Doesn't all the matter… fusing together imply a contracting universe?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin "All the matter *in the reachable universe*", not "all the matter". I.e. the matter in the galaxy will remain reachable because it is gravitationally bound, but everything else will be too far away and receding too fast to reach (assuming the universe doesn't later contract and barring something like an [Alcubierre drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive)).

Comment: The question is about interstellar travel. Not intergalactic travel. So the argument against it shouldn't be that galaxies didn't exist. It'd have to be that stars didn't exist.

Comment: @JBentley What difference are you making with "reachable"?

You and Nick012000 suggest that galaxies contract while everything else recedes.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin The expansion is accelerating which means that eventually even nearby galaxies will be receding faster than the speed of light, making them unreachable. I think you misunderstood "fused together". That was simply a reference to the fact that our galaxy and andromeda are on course to eventually merge.

Comment: As I was writing a new Comment, Star Trek said"… obviously, the rate of expansion has accelerated."

Comment: @JBentley Accelerating expansion or not, whether galaxies receding faster than light must be unreachable seems highly doubtful…

Galaxies receding faster than light require new rules but that receding FTL makes them unreachable reads like a conclusion of our own, old rules.

Comment: I think this is a great answer, because of the reference to initial conditions:  Davis (of Davis & Lineweaver fame, as a designer of their much-used graphic depicting horizons in relation to the Hubble sphere) has said that the Hubble flow's not a "force or drag" carrying stars or galaxies with it, but had not mentioned initial conditions on that occasion.  ("Initial" would, in the multiverse concept becoming more common among cosmological models, refer to a "local universe", generally larger than any region observable by any of that LU's inhabitants.)

Answer (score 15):

Although the distance between stars doesn't really change due to the expansion of space over the evolution of the universe, the region of space around our Sun is quite sparse compared to some places in the universe. As such, your desired conditions could exist not in the remote past but today, just in a different location.

[Here's an article](https://webbtelescope.org/resource-gallery/articles/pagecontent/filter-articles/what-is-the-center-of-our-galaxy-like?keyword=Black%20Holes&filterUUID=a776e097-0c60-421c-baec-1d8ad049bfb0) which says "In the center of the galaxy, stars are only 0.4–0.04 light-years apart". 0.04 light years is less than 15 light days.

And [another article I found with some quick googling](https://astronomy.com/magazine/ask-astro/2006/01/how-close-can-stars-get-to-each-other-in-galaxy-cores) claims:

> But some galaxies pack stars even tighter. M32, one of the Andromeda Galaxy's satellites, has the highest measured stellar density of any nearby galaxy — around 20 million stars per cubic parsec in its core! Not even HST can resolve M32's core into individual stars. A typical stellar separation at this density works out to 0.008 light-year, or 500 AU — about 12 times the Sun-Pluto distance — between stars.

0.008 light years is just shy of 3 light days.

These figures come from "average" or "typical" distances to nearest neighbour in dense regions, implying that there will be some even closer than that. How much closer is possible/plausible, I couldn't really say.

Comment: It is doubtful, however, that such regions of space would support  or evolve life as we know it.

Comment: @eps Would it even allow for stable planetary orbits?

Comment: @nick012000 Yes it would. Unless you down to something more like 15 hours than 15 days, Jupiter stays in orbit.

Comment: Maybe not if the star at the end of the 15 light-day trip were a supermassive black hole.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer These figures come from the typical separation distances in galactic cores, where there are billions of stars packed (relatively) close together. A supermassive black hole is not a "typical" neighbouring star.

Comment: The OP's question may've had less to do with actual travel than with spatial expansion:  As far as travel in a region with stars close together (like galactic core areas), the problem's that collisions of stellar material, and effects of intense radiation on material that might have (in a kinder environment) evolved into life would, instead, have left the evolution of any civilization capable of launching a ferryboat in its home planet's waters unlikely to continue as far as its manufacture of, say, airplanes.  That's why earth's location near the surface of a spiral arm was advantageous.

Comment: @ben - this question is about time, and as we currently don't really know where smbh's come from, we don't know if, at some point in the past, there were more stars closer to a smbh than to other stars. If smbh's came first then drew in the gas from which stars initially formed then it seems likely that they would have formed closer to the smbh where the gas was at its highest density. At which point, it is possible that a typical nearest neighbour was a smbh. It could also be the case that in the future, all matter will fall into a smbh, making it the nearest neighbour again.

Comment: And even 3 light days is a hell of a lot. It's about three times the distance that Voyager 1 traveled so far, putting a question mark behind "in our lifetimes", even when assuming that the next star system would actually harbour a habitable candidate (the chances against which are, well, *astronomical*...)

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer -- Supermassive black holes aren't stars at all:  SMBH's are formed by dust collapse across large regions.